# NGINX: Preventing Downloading of Script Files and Execute Instead

Tags: php, nginx

I see this question asked 1001+ times and frankly can't believe this is even possible with nginx and an PHP setup.  I'm having to fix a legacy app in production, nginx and php-fpm are running on the same box - which means they share this directory.

My situation is different than 99.999% of the setups out there in that I am only allowing a STATIC-like site to be served; but, allowing 2 or 3 small PHP script pages to load.  **I do not want to allow any execution of the PHP runtime unless explicit URIs have been matched.**

Unfortunately, if someone was to 'guess' a php file on the server, it downloads!

## A Blanket no-holds-bar temp-fix

I have what I think is a fix.  But I need someone with more nginx experience than I to verify this since it is a sensitive site.  I did this by just blanketly ignoring anything PHP:

```
#
# case-insensitive match of anything *.php
location ~* \.php {
    # never allow a single .php page to run, ever.
    # no parsing, no lookup, nada.  stop dead in tracks.
    return 404;
}
```

**Without this block, nginx sends the /var/www/cat-videos/cats.php file below as a download!**

## The Root Cause of Downloads from Nginx

I figured out nginx downloads the files because (*drumroll - as no one EVER has EVER explained why this happens - drumroll*):

- nginx.conf has `default_type` set to `application/octet-stream` (aka Download).  changing this to, say, `text/plain` displays the PHP instead of downloading it.  that proves that this config var is part of it.
- nginx will serve all files from the `root` directory regardless of type.  if no mime-type is matched, it will use the `default_type` above.

And there you have it.  If you don't want it served, don't put the files where nginx can see it!  (instead, move all php files to another directory, outside of your `root` directive, and configure fastcgi to talk elsewhere).  E.g. `/var/www/mysite-scripts-only/` instead of `/var/www/mysite-static-version/`.

## NGINX Security Best Practices?

What are the best practices for php and static sites to prevent this?  Move the scripts to a different directory?  Operating two different servers, and use `proxy_pass`?

I'm thinking it is best to completely separate all script files (python, php, ruby, etc - all scripts of any type) from your static files.  And setup specific `location` directives for type, where you can control script access via `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi` or `passenger` or alike in a different directory.

This allows nginx to serve, by default, anything from the static site as it is, well static.

And no, I am not talking about "just add X to your `location` and fastcgi should prevent downloads` - no.  I need complete assurance this will never happen again.  And separating script files from static files seems to be the only 100% fool-proof way of doing this because nginx just wants to serve everything in its root directory.

There may be more specific `location` overrides or url rewriting that will prevent all requests from passing through in nginx as well.  There's also the possibility of playing with additional `root` directives *inside of* `location` - but from what I read, that is generally frowned upon.  But, it was out of scope and time to resolve this matter.

## What Worked

For the record, here was my previous nginx config that prevented php from downloading:

- Nginx 1.10
- php-fpm 7.0
- Using docker, and not touching the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Here's the relevant `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` below. (not using `conf.d/*`, doesn't matter).

```
http {
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    gzip                on;
    ...
    proxy_cache_path    /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=reverse_cache:60m inactive=90m max_size=1000m;
    ...

    server {
        ...

        # Domain
        server_name      somerandomurl.blah;
        root             /var/www/cat-videos;

        ############################################
        # STATIC FILES SECTION
        ############################################
        location  / {
            index index.html
            try_files index.html =404;
        }
        location /assets/css/ {
        }
        location ~* .(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|css|txt)$ {
            proxy_cache_valid  200 120m;
            proxy_cache_lock   on;
            expires            1d;
            access_log         off;
        }

        ############################################
        # DYNAMIC PHP AREA ** DANGER ZONE **
        ############################################

        #
        # case-insensitive match of anything *.php
        location ~* \.php {
            # never allow a single .php page to run, ever.
            # no parsing, no lookup, nada.  stop dead in tracks.
            return 404;
        }

        # expose only 1 PHP page.
        # NOTE the SCRIPT_FILENAME I am setting manually.  This works fine.
        # for normal php sites, you'd most likely want to setup clean urls
        # and not use the php suffix, and use some of the normal vars you
        # see in the 1001+ tutorials out there.
        location ~ /process/cat-videos {
            include                 fastcgi_params;
            #fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass            php:9000;
            fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/cat-videos/cats.php;
        }
```

That was the old config.  I've since separated out all scripts from the static directory, and configured fastcgi to talk to the other directory like:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mysite-scripts-only/cats.php;
```

Those of you wanting to keep it dynamic, may want to change it to:

```
# don't use $document_root prefix on the path, move scripts elsewhere
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mysite-scripts-only$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why `python` tag? Why `ruby`?

Comment: @leovp if you have a `file.py` or `file.rb` sitting in your nginx `root` directory, expecting that it is safe from being served up - you aren't.  it will be served if no `location` matches it.  this question applies to all of those of configs.

Comment: But this is `nginx` configuration issue. No `python` / `ruby` code is needed to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked with many more users on nginx and this setup and there doesn't really seem to be any other way than what I have described in the original question.

They said *splitting the scripts from the static files by using different root directories* is really the best way, and I have already done that.

Therefore, marking my own question answered as it really should be a Wiki at this point.